# Git - Fixing conflict between master and feature branch before pull request

Tags: git, github, branch, pull

I have to make a pull request to a repo.
I clone the project and it has only one branch : `master`

I checkout a new branch `feature` and commit my changes to this branch.

I push my branch to Github and I'm now able to make a pull request. So I do it but it tells me now that I have conflicts.
[image]

I understand the problem. `master` is ahead of `feature` because I didn't "pull" the last changes that have been made to master when I waas working on `feature`.

How can I fix it ? How can I "pull" the last changes of master into my `feature` branch ?

Comment: You'll need to merge or rebase locally and push the result.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Fixing via merge:**

```
git fetch origin         # gets latest changes made to master
git checkout feature     # switch to your feature branch
git merge master         # merge with master
# resolve any merge conflicts here
git push origin feature  # push branch and update the pull request
```

**Fixing via rebase:**

```
git fetch origin         # gets latest changes made to master
git checkout feature     # switch to your feature branch
git rebase master        # rebase your branch on master
# complete the rebase, fix merge conflicts, etc.
git push --force origin feature
```

Note carefully that the `--force` option on the push after rebasing is probably required as the rebase effectively rewrites the `feature` branch.  This means that you need to overwrite your old branch in GitHub by force pushing.

Regardless of whether you do a merge or a rebase, afterwards the conflicts should be resolved and your reviewer should be able to complete the pull request.

Comment: Hey, jumping on here. Same case, but after either fix I end up with a feature branch with commits from other branches that weren't previously in its history. Any insight as to why that may be?

Answer (score 8):

```
$ git checkout feature                  
$ git fetch
$ git pull origin master
```

Now conflicts should occur. Now if you want to keep master's changes

```
$ git status                           # See the untracked files (conflict files)
$ git checkout --theirs <file-name>    # Accept the master's change
```

Or, If you want to keep yours (`features` changes ):

```
$ git checkout --ours <file-name>
```

Add, commit and push in `feature` branch

```
$ git commit -am <commit-message>      # Add & Commit
$ git push origin HEAD                 # Push to remote feature branch
```